# Twilio fetch all call logs from last 5 days in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I want to fetch the call logs for the last 5 days, I read on the documentation

```
You can also specify an inequality, such as EndTime<=YYYY-MM-DD, to read calls that ended on or before midnight of this date
```

I am trying the following with no luck

```
@client.calls.list(to: phone_number, end_time: ">=#{Time.now - 5.days}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are several things here, and I need to apologise for at least one of them.

Firstly, the less than/greater than equal that the Twilio API implemented was actually a bit of a hack with the way the parameters are formatted. The parameter  as the docs point out is `EndTime<=YYYY-MM-DD` but this is made of the parameter name `EndTime<` and the parameter value `YYYY-MM-DD` separated by `=`. I apologise that this seemed like a cool hack but actually made things harder.

The Ruby library actually tries to unpick this and make it more sensible again. You can use the parameter `end_time_after` instead of trying to form the correct `end_time` format.

Second, I ran the string you were using for the `end_time` and it produced this:

```rb
irb(main):001:0> ">=#{Time.now - 5.days}"
=> ">=2021-02-28 14:35:44 +1100"
```

So when a time is stringified in Ruby, it doesn't just show up in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

So, to fix your API call, should format the date to `YYYY-MM-DD` and use `end_time_after`. Note, since you're using ActiveSupport, you can also call on `5.days.ago` instead of `Time.now - 5.days`.

This should work for you:

```rb
@client.calls.list(to: phone_number, end_time_after: "#{5.days.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}")
```

Let me know if this helps at all.